# How to fix the ShiningPanda virtualenv error with gnureadline on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

`Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gnureadline`

Error:

```
DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o
  In file included from Modules/2.x/readline.c:31:0:
  ./readline/readline.h:385:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gnureadline.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`Mange Jenkins` settings:

```
Python : CPython-2.7
Path: /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `gnureadline` was in my `requirements.txt` and when building the virtual environments and installing requirements it could not install the package.

`gnureadline` isn't required on most OSes. As [Ludwig](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt) points out in this [post](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-gnureadline/issues/43):

> gnureadline [is only needed] on platforms that don't provide readline
>   at all, or that substitute readline for an incompatible product like
>   libedit (i.e. Mac OS X)

So the solution was simply to remove `gnureadline` from `requirements.txt`